# Cloth physics not updating the passive rigid body component

Tags: mesh, rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation, rigidbody

[image: Video]

## Steps I took:

### Added a plane mesh and changed:

1. **Subdivided 20** times
2. Added cloth simulation and pinned the edges, ***changed properties:***
   Quality Steps: **20**
   Collisions > Quality: **5**
3. Added Rigid Body, ***changed properties:***
   Type: **Passive**
   Collisions > Shape: **Mesh**
   Collisions > Source: **Base / Deform**

### Added a cube mesh and changed:

1. Added Rigid Body, ***changed properties:***
   Type: **Active**
   Collisions > Shape: **Box**
2. Added Collision

**Result:** The rigid body on the plane mesh seemed to ignore the cloth physics and just remained static.

**Side note:** The cloth physics are broken when rendering if not baked.

---

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/130IBYfo-6UWzC49Tv1sWqllsuR-7PRgA/view?usp=sharing

Someone asked for the file

Answer (score 0):

For the cube,add cloth not rigidbody.For the plane,add cloth and collision.Don't use rigidbody.I can't explain why clearly,but it works.

Comment: That would be cloth and collision interacting or cloth on cloth physics, that's not what I want tho.  
I would like the passive rigid body on the plane to update with the cloth physics.

Comment: I don't understand,passive means no change,but cloth is changing,what do you want?

Comment: what I want is the effect of catching the cube on the cloth while the cube is a rigid body